# Is there a way to generate the MANIFEST.MF for an Eclipse plug-in project with m2eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, osgi, m2eclipse

I have a mavenized Eclipse plug-in project and I would like to be able to generate an OSGi-ready manifest for it. Is this supported by m2eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a maven project, you can use the [Maven Bundle Plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) for this.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed [maven-bundle-plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html), when using eclipse also have a look at the "Eclipse/PDE integration" chapter to put the MANIFEST.MF in a location eclipse understands.